# iPhone SDK update existing conatct in phone book

Tags: iphone, sdk

I am able to create new contact using ABAddressBookRef. Is it posible to automatically update a particular contact with some values in database?

Thanks

Comment: The address book won't sense that your database has been updated.  You need to write code.  Do you have a database?  Do you have code that's updating it that can also update the address book?  I thin the problem would be the other way around - if the address book is updated outside your app (likely) how do you update your db

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have a sqlite database where I store some user informations. I only want to update a particular contact with  database information. I am creating new contacts with the code ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();. Is there any such method in iPhone SDK to update a particular contact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can update a particular record from the addressbook. For that you need to know the person's recordID and pass it to the following you will get the existing person's record. Then set the values for the properties. If you want to change any value then first remove earlier and then set the new one. For person's recordID if u are storing the person's record in the same application then at that time you can keep the IDs in an array. In my application I was showing the addressbook records in tableview so while fetching them I had stored their recordIds in an array. You can refer the code below:

```
ABAddressBookRef ab = ABAddressBookCreate();
ABRecordRef newPerson = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(ab, id);
if(newPerson != NULL){
    if(![firstName.text isEqual:firstname]){
        ABRecordRemoveValue(newPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty,nil);
        ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty,      firstName.text,nil);
    }
   }
ABAddressBookSave(ab,nil);
```